Does operational amplifier quiescent current depend on output current/voltage?
I have measured the OPA237 supply currents for different positive and negative output voltages (by setting V7 and V8, one always at 0V) using a differential amplifier as show in this simulation:

I got the following results:

I was surprised that the positive supply current changed significantly when the output voltage/current was negative. I expected the quiescent current would stay the same, so the positive supply current would stay the same and the negative supply current would be the sum of still the same quiescent current and output current.
The same effect can be seen for the other output polarity, even though if is less pronounced.
When I simulated this OPA237 circuit, I got what I would have expected: a constant (200uA) quiescent current (regardless of output current) in both the positive branch and negative supply branch whenever the output current was drawn from the other branch. In the model the quiescent current does not seem to depend on the output current/voltage.

I then made another simulation with a different operational amplifier, the OPA1177:

The results of the simulation are:

As can be seen, the effect of the supposedly "inactive" supply branch (inactive in terms of providing output current), which occurred when I measured the OPA237, is present here too.
Why does the quiescent current of an operational amplifier differ in the positive and negative branch depending on the output current/voltage? What exactly happens in the operational amplifier? Does this depend on the amplifier type?

Why don't you subtract load current from your results to get a better understanding of the supply currents because the currents you call quiescent cannot be quiescent.


Why does the quiescent current of an operational amplifier differ in
the positive and negative branch depending on the output
current/voltage?

The circuit is not symmetrical- for example on-chip BJTs may be much better if NPN than if PNP, so the use of the latter will be minimized. Supply currents, in general, will change both with input voltages and output voltages, even with no load current. Both within and outside normal operating range. If you go outside the input common mode range, for example, the internal current sources may not be able to work, so the supply current may drop. Or if you put current through an input protection diode the supply current may increase.

What exactly happens in the operational amplifier?

Most relatively modern op-amps such as the ones you cite are supplied without any (even simplified) schematic of the internal workings so it's hard to say. Older op-amps such as the  741, 358 and 4558 have representative schematics in the datasheets, and you can find transistor-level models.

Does this depend on the amplifier type?

Most definitely.
I would not expect models to be very accurate in this regard, so actual measurements are required- most models don't simulate the internal circuit fully, for various reasons such as speed and to protect IP. Some don't even respect Kirchoff (they have internal nodes that are connected to ground). A few types of op-amp circuits (eg. some buffer designs) depend on supply currents to behave in a certain range  to be functional, for example, and you'd want to carefully measure real parts before going that route.


When I simulated this OPA237 circuit, I got what I would have expected

Most op-amp simulation models do a poor job of simulating supply currents. That's because the model is not "transistor-level", to keep the simulation speed reasonably fast, and also not to disclose the detailed internal schematic of the device.
IOW, the model is lying :)
If you need it for something, you can always do at least a static characterization of operating point vs. supply pin current. Operating point would be described e.g. by the vector [temperature, output current, output voltage, common mode voltage, positive supply voltage, negative supply voltage] for closed-loop operation. It is also possible to do a dynamic characterization, with some polynomial approximating the impulse or step response at each operating point. You could then make a SPICE model that is much closer to real behavior. It would take quite an effort to do such characterization. And all you'd get is the characterization of one device. You'd then need to characterize a lot of them, and instead of constant parameters, derive their distributions. Since the parameters of the model won't be independent, it'd be quite a bit of theoretical work to set it all up, and then have SPICE follow through.

Why does the quiescent current of an operational amplifier differ in the positive and negative branch depending on the output current/voltage?

It does so due to internal implementation details of the op-amp. Real op-amps have to use various techniques to attain their specifications. The unspecified behaviors often have to deviate from ideal so that the specified behavior is as desired.

What exactly happens in the operational amplifier?

Simplifying, there are some finite impedances present in the design where  you'd want to imagine current sources/sinks with infinite impedance. Those impedances may also be nonlinear, so they won't be constant vs. the voltage across the impedance. Those impedances are connected between nodes that don't remain a fixed voltage apart during
changing operating point of the op-amp.
A modern op-amp may well have on the order of a hundred internal nodes. It'd be rather impressive if the idle current was perfectly constant, given this complexity.

Does this depend on the amplifier type?

Absolutely yes.

In support of your claim that simulators model supply current poorly, I'll add that CircuitLab doesn't model it at all!

The exact behavior will depend on how the output stage is implemented. Opamps use a Class AB type output, so current is running through it when there is no output current. An ideal Class AB stage would cut off the current running through it completely, when output current is large, i.e. you would see a reduced quiescent current for any large output current, but it is not always realized in this ideal way:

It can be asymmetric because of N transistors being preferred over P transistors or vice versa
It can be not worth it, because op-amps are used with lots of feedback, so the exact behavior of the output stage is often irrelevant.
Users usually care only about the quiescent current at low/zero output current, so as long as quiescent current remains much lower than the drive capability, it is good enough.

In summary, there are many different ways how to make the Class AB output stages, especially when it comes to rail-to-rail stages. These details are mostly irrelevant and to some extent company "secrets". This is just something to keep in mind when modelling analog things with many transistors. The models usually provide greatly simplified behavior and avoiding some mistakes with opamps is unfortunately up to design experience.
